# Remove first key,value pair from array that matches a custom value I define

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Apples [Query] => Apples ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Bananas [Query] => Bananas ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Bananas [Query] => Bananas ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Oranges [Query] => Oranges ) )
```

Unfortunately I have no control over the original structure of this array. So this is what we have to work with.

What I am trying to do is remove only the *first* key,value pair that matches a custom value that I define.

For Example:

```
$toRemove = 'Bananas';
```

Applied to a yet unknown miracle piece of code would result in:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Apples [Query] => Apples ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Bananas [Query] => Bananas ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Oranges [Query] => Oranges ) )
```

Notice how the second set of Bananas values remained untouched. I don't mind if you want to re-index because of gap this creates.

And if it wasn't challenging enough this needs to be done without a for loop.

Comment: why exactly do you have the "for loop restriction" ?

Comment: If your array is not fixed then, check my updated answer.

Comment: How do I nominate correct answer?

Comment: sorry first time im using stackoverflow.com

Comment: @myfirststack [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...this needs to be done without a for loop.

If you don't want to use any kind of loop, then follow this recursive method:

```
function removeElement(&$origArr, $arr, $element, $prevKey = null){
    static $flag = false;
    if($flag){
        return;
    }
    if(is_array(current($arr))){
        removeElement($origArr, next($arr), $element, key($arr));
    }else{
        if(current($arr) == $element){
            $flag = true;
            unset($origArr[$prevKey]);
            return;
        }else{
            removeElement($origArr, next($arr), $element, key($arr));
        }
    }
}

// suppose $arr is your original array
removeElement($arr, $arr, 'Bananas');

// display $arr array
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Apples' (length=6)
      'Query' => string 'Apples' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Bananas' (length=7)
      'Query' => string 'Bananas' (length=7)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Oranges' (length=7)
      'Query' => string 'Oranges' (length=7)
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)
- [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)
- [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)
- [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

---

Later, if you want to rearrange the indices numerically then use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function, like this:

```
removeElement($arr, $arr, 'Bananas');

$newArr = array_values($arr);
var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: For those who can use loops @Sougata answer was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

A loop and a check can be useful.

```
$toRemove = 'Bananas';
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    if($value[0] === $toRemove) { // add more checks if you need ($value['Query'] === $toRemove)
        unset($yourArray[$key]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed that `without loop`.. In that case a recursive function would be better!!

Answer (score 0):

If your array is not fixed then,

Try this function:-

```
 function remove_element_by_value($arr, $val) {
       $return = array(); 
       foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
          if(is_array($v)) {
             $return[$k] = remove_element_by_value($v, $val); //recursion
             continue;
          }
          if($v == $val) continue;
          $return[$k] = $v;
       }
       return $return;
    }

   $result = remove_element_by_value($arr,'Bananas');
```

Hope it will help you :)